# Fatal error: Call to a member function query()on a non-object

Tags: mysql

i used the below code ,which generates an fatal error .

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "", "") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("") or die(mysql_error());

$sel12 = $db->query("SELECT * FROM ".SPICE." WHERE status=1 ORDER BY spice_id desc LIMIT 0 , 9"); 
if(mysql_num_rows($sel12)>0){
$m=0;
?>
<?php 
while($row12=mysql_fetch_array($sel12)){ ?>

<a href="<?php echo SITE; ?>air/<?php echo $row12['spice_id']; ?>/<?php echo $m+1; ?>" title="<?php echo $row12['title']; ?>"></a>
<?php $m++; } ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in /home/tolly25/public_html/slideshow.php on line 49

Comment: you have mess of PDO and simple mysql-API.

Comment: database not mentioned here. But i used in website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query

```
$sel12 = $db->query('query');
```

should be

```
$sel12 = mysql_query('query');
```

Comment: Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/air/public_html/air.php

Comment: hope you substitute your query instead of `'query'`? If so, then there is probably error in your query

Comment: $sel12 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".SPICE." WHERE status=1 ORDER BY spice_id desc LIMIT 0 , 9"); 
my query but it still generates

Comment: what is SPICE? spice can't be a valid variable. Try to echo the query, I think the table name should be missing. Think it should be $SPICE???

Answer (score 1):

`mysql_select_db("")`  - empty DB?

use `mysql_query` instead of `$db->query`

Comment: database not mentioned here. But i used in website

Comment: Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/air/public_html/air.php