# PHP MySQLi Fatal call to member function fetch_array() for a non-object

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, fetch

Yes...this question has been posted many times. Here's an example: [Fatal error: Call to a member function query()on a non-object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11548803/fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-queryon-a-non-object). But I've looked through many of these duplicate posts and cannot find a solution

I pulled this (working) code from this website ( [nine-to-five](http://ninetofive.me/blog/build-a-live-search-with-ajax-php-and-mysql) )

But I revised my code (which is different from the SO post) to include the code mentioned in the post's answers and I'm still getting an error:

```
// Credentials
  $dbhost = "localhost";
  $dbname = "qmsdb";
  $dbuser = "root";
  $dbpass = "";

  //    Connection
  global $tutorial_db;

  $tutorial_db = new mysqli();
  $tutorial_db->connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
  $tutorial_db->set_charset("utf8");

  //    Check Connection
  if ($tutorial_db->connect_errno) {
     printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $tutorial_db->connect_error);
     exit();
  }


  // Get Search
     $search_string = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9]/", " ", $_POST['query']);
     $search_string = $tutorial_db->real_escape_string($search_string);

  // Check Length More Than One Character
     if (strlen($search_string) >= 1 && $search_string !== ' ') {

  // Build Query
  $query = 'SELECT * FROM compressors WHERE MUNPN LIKE "%'.$search_string.'%" OR name LIKE "%'.$search_string.'%"';

  // Do Search
  $result = mysql_query($query);
  while($results = $result->fetch_array()) {  
    $result_array[] = $results;
}

    .... more code that doesn't apply....

    }
```

The error is: "Fatal call to member function fetch_array() on a non object" and the line points to:

```
    while($results=$results->fetch_array()) {
```

I'm very new to Php/MySQL - so any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

.

Comment: you are mixing mysql and mysqli_

Comment: You use MySQLi to connect(`new mysqli();`) and then `mysql_query` to execute the query. That wouldn't work.

Comment: ^--« ... *meaning,* change `$result = mysql_query($query);` to `$result = mysqli_query($query);`

Comment: If *"more code that doesn't apply"* means having more `mysql_*` functions, then stop right there.

Comment: I changed to `mysqli_query($query)` but I now get an error "mysqli_query expects at least 2 parameters"

Comment: I now changed it to `mysqli_query($tutorial_db,$query);` but now I get the "fetch_array() not an object" error

Answer (score 1):

`mysql_*()` functions are **NOT**, and have **NEVER** been, object-oriented:

```
$tutorial_db = new mysqli();
                        ^----note the "i"


$result = mysql_query($query);
               ^-- note the LACK of an "i"
while($results = $result->fetch_array()) { 
                ^^^^^^^^---- not an object, because mysql_*() functions are NOT objects
```

You cannot use a DB handle/object created in one DB library (pdo, mysqli, mysql) in any of the other libraries. They may all be talking to MySQL under the hood, but their respective handles/objects are NOT inter-compatible.

Comment: *"They may all be talking to MySQL under the hood*... but they're not going to the drive-in together tonight".

Comment: Thank you. But this still doesn't make sense. How does the original code (from the nine-to-five) website work but not this?

Comment: probably because it either never did, or you introduced typos when you modified it for your own uses.