# Query SQL DB Table view and display results in HTML table

Tags: php, html, mysql, odbc

my purpose is to display in a HTML table the result of a query to a remote ODBC SQL database with PHP.
I've already established the connection with the database, but when i try to execute a query and display it in a table it doesn't show anything.
Is there a difference in the query syntax if the table is a view?
The environment is WAMP installed on Windows, PHP 5.6.19, APACHE 2.4.18

This is the code (I have omitted the variables for the odbc connection):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
     border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<?php


$conn=odbc_connect("Driver={SQL Server};Server=$server;Database=$database;", $user, $password);

if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( odbc_error(), true));

     $sql = "SELECT * FROM ASSET_VIEW";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<table><tr><th>numero</th></tr>";
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr><td>".$row["N_IMMA"]."</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
}



?>
</body>
</html>
```

All I get is the "Connection established" string and that's it.
I would like to show all the results from the table (about 30 columns and 300 rows). I've tried with different tables but I still get the same result. I'm relatively new to PHP and MySql and maybe it's a silly request but I can't get my head around it for the moment.

Thank you

Comment: My guess is: You're restricted to these functions: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.uodbc.php

Answer (score 2):

You haven't closed the else bracket for Connection could not be esatblished. That's why the Table part is not getting genearted.

```
if( $conn ) {
 echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
 echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
 die( print_r( odbc_error(), true));
}
// Logic to build the table from query
```

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure that was the problem; following the advise of @KIKO Software, i looked in the odbc function and changed the code accordingly: 

<blink>$query = "SELECT [NU_INT] FROM [INPROGRESS_WO_VIEW]"; $result = odbc_exec($conn, $query); while(odbc_fetch_row($result)){ $name = odbc_result_all($result); //$surname = odbc_result_all($result, 3); //print("$name\n $surname\n"); } odbc_close($conn); – Adex.andros 31 mins ago
</blink>

Comment: user2445413 is right. Only when there is no Connection, the site tries to get the data from the database. And otherwise, there will be only the Output "Connection established".

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work either; if I close all the brackets correctly it throws this error: " Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on resource in" - I think i should then use mysqli instead of mysql but I'm not sure as to how it works

Comment: Try using $conn_query . See if it works [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11548803/fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-queryon-a-non-object

Comment: Probably @sourabh1024 was right, but the real problem was tah I wasn't using the proper function for odbc connection;
Also, I had to switch to a Windows set-up because working with a SQL database from OSX was onestly too much prep work, because of required driver, etc. Anyway, thank you to everyone